# using 'form' in 'login.html' I got this error message. 'url' requires a non-empty first argument

Tags: django

NoReverseMatch at /accounts/login/
'url' requires a non-empty first argument. The syntax changed in Django 1.5, see the docs.
And the code where error is being shown in 'login.html', is

```
<form method="post"  action="{% url django.contrib.auth.views.login %}">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the quotes around the name of your url:

```
{% url 'django.contrib.auth.views.login' %}
```